# Boot priority for smbd/nmbd

Tags: ubuntu

What would be the ideal boot priority for smbd and nmbd? I have a server that runs samba shares and when it restarts it doesn't seem to resolve netbios requests from other clients even with the smbd and nmbd daemons running. I always have to do a "service smbd restart" for the clients to start accessing shares.

I also get a "standard input is not a socket, assuming -D" from the logs. nmbd doesn't give any log info. 
From the logs, my eth0 gets an IP much later even if networking or network-manager has a higher boot priority. So, my other question would be, for all the networking services to run, what would be the preferred boot order of all the services that should run before there is any external communication.

Thanks!

Comment: And your distribution is?

Comment: it's ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

It was smbd.conf and inetd.conf issue. 
By default, there was no nmbd entry in the inetd which caused the netbios issue at startup.